# c# Consumir web service facturacion electronica

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Soy algo nuevo en esto de consumir `webservices`, tengo que enviar un archivo a un web service y recibir una respuesta, mi problema es que no he podido generar un `SOAP Header` valido.

El web service a consumir es este:

```
https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl
```

las especificaciones en el documento son que el header debe quedar asi:

Ejemplo de petición usando Base64

```
POST /B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 3342
Host: 192.168.250.65:9080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>8ac82326-3016-430f-8d69-9efc4bcefd8f</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>6361b7b5322acb07ced00a35a85a4cc5183da3a42ede0b07f578067a18425a55</wsse:Password>
<wsse:NonceEncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">FmbZRkx1jh2A+imgjD2fLQ==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2015-10-06T12:00:33.762Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Pero por mas que trato, lo unico que he podido obtener es esto:

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-c635f931-8274-4d3d-82a1-460a2f04af73-1">
<o:Username>22ffb485-64bc-4619-8a63-340de2dd7eec</o:Username>
<o:Password>+eho+ADhrJkwZtKGabXIZOEX/0YVa206TmKnQSwt+qE=</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
const string apiUrl = "https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica",
        apiUserName = "8ac82326-3016-430f-8d69-9efc4bcefd8f";

        string apiPassword = "6361b7b5322acb07ced00a35a85a4cc5183da3a42ede0b07f578067a18425a55";

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(apiUrl));

        SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        securityElement.AllowInsecureTransport = false;
        securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;

        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
        HttpsTransportBindingElement transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

        //basic prueba
        BasicHttpSecurityMode securityMode = new BasicHttpSecurityMode();
        BasicHttpBinding binding2 = new BasicHttpBinding(securityMode);

        // Then assign username and password based on the proxy. For example -
        //var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("");
        WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortNameClient service = new WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortNameClient(binding, endpointAddress);
        //WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortNameClient service = new WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortNameClient(binding2, endpointAddress);
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = apiUserName;
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = apiPassword;
        var Obtnonce = GetNonce();
        byte[] archivo = FileToByteArray(@"c:\temp\ws_f0816002834000000000A.zip");

        service.Open();

        WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica enviofactura = new WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica();

        enviofactura.NIT = "816002834";
        enviofactura.InvoiceNumber = "10";
        enviofactura.IssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-01-01 05:00:00");
        enviofactura.Document = archivo;

        //temporal

        WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion = new WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion();
        WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta envioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta = new WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta();
        WSDian.AcuseRecibo acuseRecibo = new WSDian.AcuseRecibo();
        WSDian.ReceivedInvoice receivedInvoice = new WSDian.ReceivedInvoice();
        WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortNameClient facturaElectronicaPortNameClient = new WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortNameClient();           

        envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1 = enviofactura;
        var versionSoap = acuseRecibo.GetType();
        acuseRecibo = service.EnvioFacturaElectronica(envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1);
```

Pero estoy obteniendo el error:

> The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized

No entiendo cómo generar la cabecera SOAP como la solicitan, ¿No debería el `wsdl` generarla de manera automática?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Añado, este es mi `Web.config`

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

 <system.diagnostics>

    <trace autoflush="true" />

    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
          <add name="MyConsole"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add
        name="MyTraceFile"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" />
      <add name="MyConsole" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>

    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>

  </system.diagnostics> 

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co:80/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11"
        contract="WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortName" name="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Para examinar el directorio raíz de la aplicación web durante la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true.
        Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información sobre la carpeta de aplicación web.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Actualizo:

Realice pruebas con el `SoapUI` de manera exitosa y me di cuenta que:

1. El usuario esta bien, es el identificador unico del software provisto por la DIAN
2. El password es el resultado de usar `SHA-256` sobre la contraseña que se configuro en el sitio de la DIAN.

Ahora, el mayor problema es generar el `<soapenv:Header>` con el `<wsse:UsernameToken>` que incluya el `<wsse:Nonce>` y `<wsu:Created>`

**Actualizo**

Despues de mucho buscar, encontre este articulo con el que logre acercarme mas a la generacion del `<soapenv:Header>`:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication

Ahora mi Header luce asi:

```html
<s:Envelope xmln s:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username><!--Removed--></wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password><!--Removed--></wsse:Password>
<wsse: Nonce>t21C05VjRqomc+OehZoSzwqhmaM=</wsse:Nonce>
<wsse:Created>2018-08-28T08:03:40.749Z</wsse:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion xmlns="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
<NIT><!--Removed--></NIT>
<InvoiceNumber>980000000</InvoiceNumber>
<IssueDate>2018-08-28T19:00:00</IssueDate>
<Document>UEsDBBQAAAAIAPBkHE3djKx2hwgAAEcdAAAeAAAAZmFjZV9mMDgxNjAwMjgzNDAwM0E2OTl.........
```

Ahora mi problema es que genera el siguiente error:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [11736] Connection#33583636 - Línea de estado recibida: Version=1.1, StatusCode=400, StatusDescription=Bad Request.

System.Net Error: 0 : [11736] Excepción en HttpWebRequest#36620214::GetResponse - Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta..

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Verifica como esta configurado el acceso al web service

Comment: No tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, acabo de publicar el `Web.config` ,  ¿a eso te refieres?

Comment: Nop, lo que me refiero es que te da este error: El token de seguridad no pudo ser autenticado o autorizado; la excepción anidada es org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: el token de seguridad no pudo ser autenticado o autorizado. Lo que indica que no puedes acceder al web service. Si la url esta bien es posible que haya un metodo de seguridad implementado en el web service.

Comment: Pues la documentacion para consumo del webservice solo especifica que:

7.1.
Autenticación
El servicio web utiliza las extensiones WSS (WS-Security), perfil UsernameToken 1.0 para autenticar el software de facturación del OFE que solicita el establecimiento de una conexión.

El software de facturación  debe  seguir  la  especificación  e  incluir  los  elementos  Username,  Password,  Nonce  y Created correspondientes para permitir su autenticación. No especifica ni siquiera la version del SOAP, si es SOAP1.1 o SOAP 1.2 y no se si esto sea lo que falla

Comment: No creo que sea soap, pero ya revisaste username, password, etc..

Comment: Debes asegurarte que usas como usuario el identificador del software que te da la Dian y el password es el resultado de aplicarle el SHA256 al password original

Comment: @FelipeTaborda ¿existe documentación al respecto de cómo consumir el servicio? `Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta.` =  es porque le falta algo.

Comment: Hola, si existe: https://www.dian.gov.co/fizcalizacioncontrol/herramienconsulta/FacturaElectronica/Factura%20Electrnica/Anexo%20Tecnico%20005%20Servicio%20de%20Recepcion%20de%20Facturas%20Electronicas%20V2.pdf

Comment: Estoy en esto tambien pero desde java con spring boot, alguien ya logró resultados con el ws de la DIAN, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente logre conectarme al servicio de la `DIAN` y obtener la respuesta exitosa:

```html
...<ns2:ResponseDateTime>2018-09-05T11:37:47.766-05:00</ns2:ResponseDateTime><ns2:Response>200</ns2:Response><ns2:Comments>Ejemplar recibido exitosamente pasará a verificación.</ns2:Comments></ns2:EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Encontré que:

1. El usuario para conectar es el id del software que entrega la DIAN al momento de registrarse
2. La contraseña es la que se configuro al registrarse y en `SHA-256`
3. No se necesita el `nonce`

La clase para realizar el envio queda así:

```html
[WebMethod]
 public string envioFacturaElectronicaSOAP()
 {
  const string apiUrl = "https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica";
  byte[] archivo = FileToByteArray(@"c:\temp\ws_f0890900161000000dab3.zip");
  EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(apiUrl));
  var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
  securityElement.AllowInsecureTransport = false;
  securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
  securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;

  var encodingElement = new //MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
          TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);

  var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
  var binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);
  
  facturaElectronicaPortNameClient Service = new facturaElectronicaPortNameClient(binding, endpointAddress);
  Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MiSoftwareID";
  Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MiContraseñaEnSHA256";
  
  WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica enviofactura = new WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica();
  enviofactura.NIT = "MiNIT";
  enviofactura.InvoiceNumber = "MiNumeroDeFactura";
  enviofactura.IssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-05-28 20:17:19"/*Fecha de la factura*/);
  enviofactura.Document = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(archivo));

  EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion = new EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion();
  envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1 = enviofactura;

  AcuseRecibo acuseRecibo = new AcuseRecibo();
  acuseRecibo = Service.EnvioFacturaElectronica(envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1);  

  return acuseRecibo.Comments.ToString();
 }
```

Tambien se puede realizar el envio usando `MTOM` como lo recomienda la DIAN, en ese caso la clase queda asi:

```html
[WebMethod]
 public string envioFacturaElectronicaMTOM()
 {
  const string apiUrl = "https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica";
  byte[] archivo = FileToByteArray(@"c:\temp\ws_f0890900162000000dad3.zip");
  EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(apiUrl));
  var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
  securityElement.AllowInsecureTransport = false;
  securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
  securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;

  var encodingElement = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
          
  

  var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
  var binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

  facturaElectronicaPortNameClient Service = new facturaElectronicaPortNameClient(binding, endpointAddress);
  Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MiSoftwareID";
  Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MiPasswordEnSHA256";

  WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica enviofactura = new WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica();
  enviofactura.NIT = "MiNIT";
  enviofactura.InvoiceNumber = "124063277";
  enviofactura.IssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-05-28 20:17:19");
  enviofactura.Document = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(archivo));

  EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion = new EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion();
  envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1 = enviofactura;

  AcuseRecibo acuseRecibo = new AcuseRecibo();
  acuseRecibo = Service.EnvioFacturaElectronica(envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1);

  return acuseRecibo.Comments.ToString();
 }
```

Mi `web.config` quedo así:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co:80/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11"
        contract="WSDian.facturaElectronicaPortName" name="facturaElectronicaPortNameSoap11" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca el valor siguiente en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Para examinar el directorio raíz de la aplicación web durante la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true.
        Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información sobre la carpeta de aplicación web.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finalmente:

1. El proyecto lo cree en `WCF` usando `C#`
2. Se debe agregar por paquete `NuGet` el paquete Microsoft.Web.Services3
3. Agregue el servicio web de la DIAN como `Referencia de servicio` (https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl)

   4. El servicio se consume como `https`, se debe realizar el cambio manualmente, ya que al agregar la referencia al servicio la toma como `http`.

Eso fue todo.

Ya lo que queda es procesar la respuesta del servicio que aun no lo he logrado por ninguno de los 2 métodos que expuse. Pero con esto se responde la pregunta que habia realizado.

Espero que esta información sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Que bueno que hayas logrado solucionarlo. Recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score -2):

Me enfrento al mismo problema, comparto la información que he encontrado hasta el momento

Según los estándares [WSS](https://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf) el `password` se calcula así:

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )
```

En el código que expones aunque especifica la línea `var Obtnonce = GetNonce();` no es claro si estas usando el `nonce` y el `timestamp` para calcular el `password_digest`.

Ahora, según los anexos técnicos de la DIAN, se debe enviar un **sha256** `( password )`, no especifica como usar el `nonce` y el `timestamp`, y de hecho en otro webservice que expone la DIAN llamado `Consulta_del_Resultado_de_Transacciones` no se pide enviar el `nonce` y el `createdtime`, como esa parte no es clara, se debería probar las diferentes variantes.

Mi recomendacion sería cambiar el código para calcular el `password` teniendo el cuenta el `nonce` y el `timestamp`:

```
SHA-256 ( nonce + created + password )
```

Tener en cuenta especificar el atributo `Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest" o Type="...#PasswordText"` dependiendo de como envíes el `password` aplicando o no `base64`.

Sigo investigando sobre el tema si encuentro algo mas, por acá lo publicaré, e igualmente si lo solucionas agradecería lo publicaras.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, jjperez89. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.