# c# WCF Error en respuesta de Webservice al consumir con SOAP MTOM de Facturacion Electronica

Tags: c#, webservice, soap, wcf

Estoy consumiendo un Servicio web para enviar un archivo

```
https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl
```

Pero en el debug me devuelve la siguiente excepción:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'Error de comprobación de seguridad de mensajes.'
>   InvalidOperationException: Signaturas de token auxiliar no esperadas.
>
> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Error de comprobación de seguridad de mensajes. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Signaturas de token auxiliar no esperadas.
>    en System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ProcessSupportingSignature(SignedXml signedXml, Boolean isFromDecryptedSource)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Security.StrictModeSecurityHeaderElementInferenceEngine.ExecuteProcessingPasses(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, XmlDictionaryReader reader)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      en System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)

Para realizar el envio del archivo realizo lo siguiente:

```
public string envioFacturaElectronicaMTOM()
{
    const string apiUrl = "https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica";
    byte[] archivo = FileToByteArray(@"c:\temp\ws_f0890900162000000dad3.zip");
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(apiUrl));
    var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
    securityElement.AllowInsecureTransport = false;
    securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
    securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;

    var encodingElement = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);



    var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
    var binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, encodingElement, transportElement);

    facturaElectronicaPortNameClient Service = new facturaElectronicaPortNameClient(binding, endpointAddress);
    Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MiSoftwareID";
    Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MiPasswordEnSHA256";

    WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica enviofactura = new WSDian.EnvioFacturaElectronica();
    enviofactura.NIT = "MiNIT";
    enviofactura.InvoiceNumber = "124063277";
    enviofactura.IssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-05-28 20:17:19");
    enviofactura.Document = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(archivo));

    EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion = new EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion();
    envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1 = enviofactura;

    AcuseRecibo acuseRecibo = new AcuseRecibo();
    acuseRecibo = Service.EnvioFacturaElectronica(envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1);

    return acuseRecibo.Comments.ToString();
}
```

En la respuesta de esta pregunta esta como estoy consumiendo el servicio web de manera completa, no lo escribo aquí ya que es extenso: [c# Consumir web service facturacion electronica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191511/c-consumir-web-service-facturacion-electronica)

Cuando hago el seguimiento con fiddler, veo lo siguiente en el Request:

```
POST https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:1a31b7a4-bb88-4bd7-aa99-6bfca75980a0+id=1";start-info="text/xml"
SOAPAction: ""
Host: facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co
Content-Length: 9191
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive


--uuid:1a31b7a4-bb88-4bd7-aa99-6bfca75980a0+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
```

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <s:Header>
  <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPonyxdQ1ypqsgAAAAAInUwvSubfkWtkosj7GNjAU+JUra/JWZAnJwNPpSrhZUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-dceca3e0-7764-477b-aac4-3e5ad3303a9f-1">
    <o:Username><!--Removed--></o:Username>
    <o:Password><!--Removed--></o:Password>
   </o:UsernameToken>
  </o:Security>
 </s:Header>
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion xmlns="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
   <NIT><!--Removed--></NIT>
   <InvoiceNumber>124063277</InvoiceNumber>
   <IssueDate>2018-05-28T20:17:19</IssueDate>
   <Document><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/636719021136260437" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></Document>
  </EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
--uuid:1a31b7a4-bb88-4bd7-aa99-6bfca75980a0+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636719021136260437>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

PK    x M h   .c     face_f0890900161000000faf3.xml |ۖ Ⱥ O Ⱦ 9 39
--uuid:1a31b7a4-bb88-4bd7-aa99-6bfca75980a0+id=1--
```

Y el response que recibo es el siguiente:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2018 12:28:33 GMT
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="----=_Part_504669_2132088323.1536323314599"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: TS0133d910=01ca0e1ef64130a10e8ff09c341631cb87ffd0b88debb404b553072ef7b937149aeae0ee703398a88c3adec21a15c42b7a1d9ebafc; Path=/
Content-Length: 3256

------=_Part_504669_2132088323.1536323314599
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
```

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-478012">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV"/>
     </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
     <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
     <ds:Reference URI="#id-478011">
      <ds:Transforms>
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
       </ds:Transform>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>gPOXTVuXDw2ktXu3Fiyjoz35JwY=</ds:DigestValue>
     </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>e7AOmryll5EXw3euAOlO2CwL+N3wpR+QHz8Zmlz+hBFZ7kmQ9QXkupO+MUkDrnHu/MsOZr7Q0j60heMbM4u3yIiTRPE0HsEOV1BQ/+v0LX+XSGo1EiHlcYbEo8Yn+aHFmR4z81TV8TycRXMBUoyJXl2Y/yLjFPH8TptpKLagEOYgcJQ340Cw7rVBfG+tuVwU388F/MDiv/vRhIjpHViSHSP8C7xO5NZvNoGsg5f66ATzkwkB4wmeAmHud3Mbuj7Vdq3Sw==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-0ACB9EF7167DC955151536323314584358508">
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-0ACB9EF7167DC955151536323314584358509">
      <ds:X509Data>
       <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=AC SUB CERTICAMARA,O=CERTICAMARA S.A,OU=NIT 830084433-7,C=CO,ST=DISTRITO CAPITAL,L=BOGOTA,STREET=www.certicamara.com</ds:X509IssuerName>
        <ds:X509SerialNumber>91436926122049919406185072624124</ds:X509SerialNumber>
       </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
      </ds:X509Data>
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-478010">
    <wsu:Created>2018-09-07T12:28:34.584Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2018-09-07T12:33:34.584Z</wsu:Expires>
   </wsu:Timestamp>
   <wsse11:SignatureConfirmation xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" wsu:Id="SC-478009"/>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-478011">
  <ns2:EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta xmlns:ns2="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura" xmlns:ns3="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ConsultaDocumentos" xmlns:ns4="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/VersionDespliegue">
   <ns2:Version>Componente DIAN</ns2:Version>
   <ns2:ReceivedDateTime>2018-09-07T07:28:34.392-05:00</ns2:ReceivedDateTime>
   <ns2:ResponseDateTime>2018-09-07T07:28:34.583-05:00</ns2:ResponseDateTime>
   <ns2:Response>200</ns2:Response>
   <ns2:Comments>Ejemplar recibido exitosamente pasará a verificación.</ns2:Comments>
  </ns2:EnvioFacturaElectronicaRespuesta>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
------=_Part_504669_2132088323.1536323314599--
--------------------------------------------------
caf
------=_Part_67971_1574199767.1536252188646
```

¿No sé qué podrá estar pasando o como debo recibir la respuesta para que el C# no me arroje la excepción?

Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La excepción se produce, porque se envía el request sin firmar `<signature>`, pero el response llega firmado. parece ser que `.net` espera una respuesta sin firma.

La manera que encontré de solucionarlo no fue la mejor, pero es funcional y permite continuar con el proceso de recepción del `response` y su correspondiente proceso. Tuve que usar un `CustomEncoder`, para poder procesar el `response` antes de que llegara para eliminar toda la firma.

Me base en este articulo: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/03/08/wcf-custom-encoder-to-read-mtom-response/  y realice modificaciones para adaptarlo a lo que necesito.

La sección que modifique de la `DLL` que cree en base al articulo anterior quedo así:

```
public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
    {
        //Convert the received buffer into a string
        byte[] incomingResponse = buffer.Array;
        incomingResponse = RemoveSignatures(incomingResponse);
        ........
```

La clase que creé `RemoveSignatures` quita la firma y devuelve el response sin firma:

```
private byte[] RemoveSignatures(byte[] stream)
    {
        string stream2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream);           
        stream2 = stream2.Replace("\0", "");

        Regex x = new Regex("(\\<SOAP-ENV:Header\\>)(.*?)(\\</SOAP-ENV:Header\\>)");            
        string repl = "";
        stream2 = x.Replace(stream2, "$1" + repl + "$3");
        byte[] streamNuevo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stream2);

        return streamNuevo;
    }
```

Esta clase la cree con ayuda de esta respuesta que encontre aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917316/configuring-a-wcf-client-to-use-username-credentials-on-the-request-and-check-ce

De esta manera `.Net` ya no genera la excepción y permite procesar el Response.

Como lo comenté en un inicio, esta solución es demasiado hack para mi gusto, pero es funcional. Espero encontrar una mejor manera, si es así la publicare.

Espero le sea de ayuda a alguien más.

Comment: Muy bueno que lo hayas documentado sobre todo para todos aquellos en Colombia que deben lidiar con el sistema de la DIAN.,

Comment: hola @Felipe Taborda también tengo el mismo problema que response llega firmado, donde llamas el metodo ReadMessage yo uso el metodo del ws:  acuseRecibo = FactElecService.EnvioFacturaElectronica(envioFacturaElectronicaPeticion.EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion1); y es ahí donde me salta el error de Signaturas de token auxiliar no esperadas.